# J1 visa for PhD refused twice. Can I still reapply?

Tags: visa, student-visa, usa

I want to reapply for a J1 visa for my PhD after two rejections with no reason given. I have funding plus a signed bond with home government for five year compulsory service and everything. I want to give it another shot as my classes will begin soon.

Can I apply from another consular station in my country as my current one has a long waiting list for appointments? I read somewhere that one has to apply from the same post or is there any flexibility in that? I could get an early interview date from the other station.

Comment: You should discuss this in depth with your US university. What did they say about it?

Comment: Post a copy of the denial letter (with your personal info redacted) to demonstrate that "no reasons were given."

Comment: Why are you applying for a J1? Normally an F1 would be the appropriate visa.